# Add number per count?

Tags: python

I want to make a program on Python that will add 5 per count until count is 20, so the total would be 100. So basically I want to show the result of 5 * 20 using this way.

```
num = 5
count = 0
total = 0
```

I tried this code but it returns as zero. Why?

```
while(count == 20):
    total = num * count
    if(total == num * count):
        count = count + 1
print total
```

Please fix any mistake I made. I'm new to Python...

Answer (score 4):

### You probably meant `while count <= 20:`

The condition specified for a while loop is what needs to be true for it to *keep* running - not for when it ends.

Also note that you don't need parentheses around the `while` and `if` conditions.

### Your code also has some odd redundancies, though.

For instance:

```
total = num * count
if total == num * count:
    count = count + 1
```

The `if` statement will always be true, given that you're setting total to the same thing you check it against, in the previous line. In other words, you could have just written...

```
total = num * count
if True:
    count = count + 1
```

or even just...

```
total = num * count
count = count + 1
```

#### Furthermore...

You set `total` equal to `num * count` on each iteration, but if your goal is just to print out `num * 20`, you don't have to count up to 20 - you can just start out at 20.

```
num = 5
count = 20
print num * count
```

#### Also note...

that this line can be more concisely stated:

```
count = count + 1
```

can also just be written as...

```
count += 1
```

### Finally...

If what you really wanted was a list of numbers in increments of 5 up to 100, you could do this:

```
>>> range(0, 101, 5)
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
```

or this:

```
>>> [n*5 for n in range(21)]
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
```

Comment: Oh wow, I will definitely make changes to my program. I'm just trying to get the hang of Python and you are a big help!